# TypeError: object of type 'pygame.surface' has no len()

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Heads or Tails game where Heads has a challenge but Tails has a different one.

I programmed the "choosing" thingy and it looks like this:

```
def imgChoose():

    choice1 = headsPNG,tailsPNG

    choosing = True
    while choosing:
        item = random.choice(random.choices(choice1, weights=map(len,choice1))[0])
        screen.blit(item(0,0))
        choosing = False
```

screen is a variable for `pygame.display.set_mode((800,800), pygame.RESIZABLE)`
headsPNG and tailsPNG are images of coins.

It should pop up on the screen either of those images but it gave me the error in the title.

Comment: What do you think `map(len,choice1)` is doing?  Because that doesn't make sense.  Also, you are missing a comma after `item` in `screen.blit(item(0,0))`.

Comment: Question is missing some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.